# How to show large xml value with scroll bar in html5

Tags: xml, html

I want to show some xml value in a div tag.
I use xmp html tag.
But sometimes my xml value consists of several lines,How can I add scroll bar for showing all lines.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tag `<xmp>` is since HTML 3.0 deprecated. From HTML 4.0 you can use the `<pre>` tag to pre-formatted your content. if your want to display some source code you include the `<code>` within your div

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow-y:scroll">
<pre>
<code>
 .... your XML content here
</code>
</pre>
```

you leave the sizing of your content to `<div>` and the formatting to `<pre>` and `<code>`

Answer (score 1):

style the div with overflow:scroll, or overflow-y to be more specific since you want lines.
for that to work you have to set an height to the div

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:500px">...</div>
```